# Theoretical time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm having trouble understanding time complexity beyond just Big O. In this example:

```
f(n) = n^10 g

g(n) = (2n)^10
```

Is f θ(g)? I'm guessing it's θ(g) because you can find a constant c1 and c2 that will allow c1*g(n) to be an upper bound of f(n) and c2*g(n) that will be a lower bound.

Comment: Your guess is correct. You can use any c1 >= 1, and any c2 <= 2^(-10).

Comment: This kind of question might find a better audience at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, f(n)=n^10 and g(n)=(2n)^10.

So, `f(n)>=((1/4)^10)*(2n)^10` is greater than g(n). So, `f(n)>=c1*g(n)` for some c1=1/4;

Similarly, `f(n)<=(c2)/*(2n)^10` is smaller than g(n) for any value of c2 **greater than or equal to 1/2**.

So, `f(n)<=c2*g(n)`.

Hence `c1*g(n)<=f(n)<=c2*g(n); where c1<1/2 and c2>1/2`.

Hence, **`f(n)=Theta(g(n))`** OR `f(n)=θ(g(n))`.

Comment: What if f(n)=n^10 and g(n)=f(f(n))? In this case would f be both θ(g) and o(g)?